# Get attributes values xml using jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, attributes

I have a part of my XML code that looks like this:

```
<GameEvents>
<g e="Build" t="60" p="1" d="structure_farm" />
<g e="Build" t="104" p="0" d="structure_farm" />
<g e="Build" t="941" p="1" d="warren_squirrel" />
</GameEvents>
```

I want to get the attribute values of e, t, p, d. This is my jQuery code:

```
var xmlString = $("#xmlInfo").val(),
xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xmlString),
$xml = $(xmlDoc),
$matchBuild = $xml.find( "GameEvents" );

console.log( $matchBuild.find("g").get(0).attr("e") );
```

This gives me and error. If I remove the .attr("e") the console writes the first g line. Like this: g e="Build" t="60" p="1" d="structure_farm"

Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan 
Error:
Uncaught TypeError: $matchBuild.find(...).get(...).attr is not a function

Comment: `.get(0)` retrieves an `XMLElement`, which does not have an `attr` function. Use `.first()`, or use `.getAttribute("e")`

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan thanks! I got it to work.